# Quiz Certificate doesn't show quiz results tokens

Tags: 7, quiz

I am building a new website to replace a Drupal 7 website that has an online training platform using [quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz), quiz_certificate and [certificate](https://www.drupal.org/project/certificate) and a custom content type called syllabus. The website also uses panels and interjections of custom php, both of which I am not interested in doing.

We need to display the date that a user passed the quiz and earned the certificate, this is of utmost important as our users return on a regular basis to earn the same certificate. The previous dev used a current date token so that whenever they download a certificate, it has the current date on it and not the date of when they passed the quiz.

I am wondering if it can't display tokens related to user's quiz results because I am using it incorrectly or it's not designed to do that, and if not then I am wondering what Certificate is supposed do when it is used with Quiz. The token for the time the quiz was passed or ended should be `end_time`.

Furthermore, anyone can access a certificate, whether they passed or not unless I block their access to it using a math equation in a view based on their score. They could theoretically just go to our website and construct a certain URL to get the certificate (`node/[nid]/certificate`). The quiz is set to "award certificate" and the individual quiz nodes are set to "manual".

If it is not possible to get quiz result-based tokens into the certificate, could I build a view that will act like a certificate?

If anyone is interested, the view I build to allow users to access their certificate if they got a passing score but not if they didn't can be [downloaded here](https://pastebin.com/nRNqCKGw). The math expression I had to use was to rewrite any non-zero number as "download certificate" with the link and then hide for zero. They get a zero for anything less than passing with `abs(([score]+1)-[pass_rate])+(([score]+1)-[pass_rate])`.